# What is the strategy to have Continuous DB Backup

Tags: mysql, database, oracle, postgresql, database-backups

I use Amazon RDS for managing my DB and I take 1 backup a day right now. I wonder how big companies plan to recover when the inevitable happens and things go haywire. Like I recently read a jr. developer messed up the Production server while following the documentation. Taking 1 backup a day doesnt seem compelling because now I loose all the day that is generated on that day up until that point. What could we possibly do to recover DB to the exact moment before something catastrophic happened?

Comment: Postgres supports PITR, see here: https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/continuous-archiving.html

Comment: Awesome, exactly what I am looking for. Thanks!